# Matlab heatmap: Making a uniform colorscale for all subplots

Tags: matlab

I have 4 different dataset `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`to generate 4 heatmaps in a subplot

```
xvalues = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'};
yvalues = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'};

subplot(2,2,1)
HA = heatmap(xvalues,yvalues,A);
HA.Title = 'A';
HA.XLabel = 'area';
HA.YLabel = 'area';

subplot(2,2,2)
HB = heatmap(xvalues,yvalues,B);
HB.Title = 'B';
HB.XLabel = 'area';
HB.YLabel = 'area';

subplot(2,2,3)
HC = heatmap(xvalues,yvalues,C);
HC.Title = 'C';
HC.XLabel = 'area';
HC.YLabel = 'area';

subplot(2,2,4)
HD = heatmap(xvalues,yvalues,D);
HD.Title = 'D';
HD.XLabel = 'area';
HD.YLabel = 'area';
```

Since each dataset has a different max and min value, the heatmap used the corresponding min and max values of each dataset for its color scale, so all 4 plots looked similar to each other. Is there a way to make a color scale so that it's uniformly used across all subplots? (will be easier to see the differences between the subplots)

Comment: Pick the colour scale to run from the lowest value across your four data sets to the highest value across your four data sets, and use that scale for all subplots.

Comment: The first google result is: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first want to get the minimum and maximum values across all of the data sets, then use these to set the [`'ColorLimits'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.heatmapchart-properties.html#property_d119e420026) of each [heatmap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/heatmap.html):

```
minValue = min([A(:); B(:); C(:); D(:)]);
maxValue = max([A(:); B(:); C(:); D(:)]);
HA.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
HB.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
HC.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
HD.ColorLimits = [minValue maxValue];
```

You could also use the [`caxis`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) function ([as you typically would for other plots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987317/52738)), although you have to [target](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html#inputarg_target) each `heatmap` object since they each have their own colormap:

```
caxis(HA, [minValue maxValue]);
caxis(HB, [minValue maxValue]);
caxis(HC, [minValue maxValue]);
caxis(HD, [minValue maxValue]);
```

Comment: The `ColorLimits` commands works greatly, but I guess if I was doing any other plot I would have to use `caxis` instead.

Comment: @Aiskya: Yes, for other plots you would use `caxis` for each *axes* object.

Comment: I appreciate your help!